# Reset pagination if there is a change in md-total during filtering

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-material

I am working on Angular JS application and using md-table for data table pagination. The library filter function is working fine with search text box but there is problem when doing search in other than first page.

The search result(s) are always being displayed on 1st page when user performs search from any other page. I have decided to configure $Watch listener on search text to reset page number to one on each search.

To make $Watch listener working I have changed ng-model as an object below. This is resulting broken search functionality. Any help in fixing this problem is highly appreciated. Below is my Controller script

```
   $scope.searchPhrase={ name :"" }; 
  $scope.query = {serverOrder:'serverName',
                  processOrder:'processName',
                  limit: 5,
                  page: 1,
                  multiSelect: false};
   $scope.$watch("searchPhrase.name", function(newValue,oldValue) { 
                console.log("Listener working");
                $scope.query.page = 1;
              console.log($scope.query.page);
                    });
```

Piece of template html.

```
    <input  ng-model="searchPhrase.name" style="color:white;">
    <tr md-row md-select="serverToConfigure" ng-repeat="s in $parent.servers  | filter :searchPhrase.name  | orderBy: query.serverOrder | limitTo: query.limit : (query.page -1) * query.limit ">
                        <td md-cell>{{s.serverId}}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{s.serverName}}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{s.environmentName}}</td>
                        <td md-cell>{{s.lastUpdated | date :"short"}}</td>
                        <td md-cell><md-icon ng-style="{'color': generateStatusColor(s.statusColor)}">{{getIconByColor(s.statusColor)}}</md-icon></td>
                        <td md-cell><md-button class="md-fab md-mini" style="background-color:#86bc25" ng-click="toggleConfigView('config');setServerToConfigure(s)" ><md-icon>build</md-icon> <md-tooltip >configure</md-tooltip></md-button></td>
                      </tr>
                    </tbody>
                  </table>
 </md-table-container>
    <md-table-pagination style="color:white" md-limit="query.limit" md-limit-options="[5, 10, 15]" md-page="query.page" md-total="{{$parent.servers.length}}"  md-page-select></md-table-pagination>
```

Earlier search was working with below configuration with problem in search results being always displayed in page one.

```
<input  ng-model="searchPhrase" style="color:white;">
```

Changed "searchPhrase" ng-model to object declaration and configured $watch listener to reset pagination has broken the Library search functionality

Comment: Try declaring the `name` property as well. Like: `$scope.searchPhrase={ name :"" }; `

Comment: @PrerakSola . Thanks Its working as expected. Is there any way to access filtered list inside watch listener ? I would like to reset pagination only when there are records for search text.

Comment: You won't have the updated list in the watch listener of search. You can create a listener for `$parent.servers` (I am assuming this is your table data) and set the paginator values in it.

Comment: @PrerakSola . $parent.servers contains all servers list. Can you please suggest how to achieve this . when user performs search on "nth" page if there are no results for the search string still I was resetting the page number to one and it should not happen. P.S I have updated both html and controller scripts